# Customizing unit choices in a django-measurement form

Tags: python, django, forms, measurement

I am quite new to Django and looking for a package that helps handling units in a Django app.

[Django-measurements](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/django-measurement) seemed like a good starting point for me and I tried to modify the units displayed in the dropdown of a form as shown in the [documentation](https://django-measurement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/forms.html):

```
# my_app/forms.py
from measurement.measures import Volume
from django_measurement.models import MeasurementField

class BeerForm(forms.Form):

    volume = MeasurementField(
        measurement=Volume,
        unit_choices=(("l","l"), ("oz","oz")),
    )
```

However when playing with this form in the django shell, it seems there are no fields:

```
from my_app.forms import BeerForm
b = BeerForm()
b.fields
>> {}
b.as_table()
>> ''
```

Am I missing something here? Any advice welcome, thanks!

```
django = "~=3.1.0"
django-measurement = "==3.2.3"
python_version = "3.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `forms.py`, `MeasurementField` should be imported from `forms`, not `models`, like this:

```
from django_measurement.forms import MeasurementField
```

The answer was provided by @codingjoe on [Github](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/django-measurement/issues/103)